# Load .pdf file / custom file from flutter assets

Tags: flutter

My question is if there is a way to load a .pdf file in app resources like **assets** when deploying **flutter app** ? I'd like to display a PDF file using this:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer

but without loading from internet ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy the asset to a temporary file.

```
  Future<File> copyAsset() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    File tempFile = File('$tempPath/copy.pdf');
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load('assets/asset.pdf');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
    return tempFile;
  }
```

Comment: For those who wonder from where getTemporaryDirectory() comes from , you need to get a library:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

Comment: @HajoLemcke The browser can't write to the local machine - even a temp folder. If you are trying to open a PDF in the browser, you could serve that PDF from the server (where you are serving your flutter web app) and use `url_launcher` to open a new window with the PDF.

Comment: Sorry. I meant any file not specifically a pdf file. I can put a file e.g. into /lib/assets/config.json and just want to load it. That should even be possible in web or not?

Comment: @HajoLemcke It just works as normal (but don't put it in `lib`). Put it in `assets/config.json`, add to `pubspec.yaml` then use, for example, `rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json').then(print);` If that doesn't work, ask a new question and feel free to tag it here.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the tip. This works. I will try now to use it in a package.

Comment: Answers like this without the proper imports are just........